# Replace null value to blank

Tags: android

In want to replace null value to blank where data is coming from JSON format.

Below is the code where response has some data which values are null I do not want to show null on my app so what can I do to change null into blank.

```
String detailsURL = "http://10.0.2.2/xp/details2.php?id="+id+"&gender="+strGender+"&curr_user_id="+current_Id;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,detailsURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.e("details*************",response.trim());
                showJSON(response);
            }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(BlankActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(BlankActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Below is the showJSON function

```
private void showJSON(String response){
       String fname = "";
       String lname = "";
       String mobile1 = "";
       String emailVC = "";
       String height = "";
       String weight = "";
       String complexion = "";
       String body = "";
       String diet = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject userData = result.getJSONObject(0);

        fname = userData.getString(Config.KEY_FNAME);
        lname = userData.getString(Config.KEY_LNAME);
        mobile1 = userData.getString(Config.KEY_MOBILE1);
        emailVC = userData.getString(Config.KEY_EMAIL);
        height = userData.getString(Config.KEY_HEIGHT);
        weight = userData.getString(Config.KEY_WEIGHT);
        complexion = userData.getString(Config.KEY_COMPLEXION);
        body = userData.getString(Config.KEY_BODY);
        diet = userData.getString(Config.KEY_DIET);
```

Comment: Post showJSON method

Comment: I have posted showJSON method please check that

Comment: it is batter to pass all String value in ""(Blank) and if the in case if Array []         (Blank Array),-----------so batter to change at service side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(jsonObject.has("key"))
{
  if (jsonObject.isNull("key"))
     {
       String value = "";
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the key @Yash

Comment: @VikasGodiyal key here is "Config.KEY_FNAME"

Comment: So there is lots of variable I need for everyone And if I do like this I will take time

Comment: @VikasGodiyal to avoid unusual crashes you need to check for all

Answer (score 1):

in your showJSON method:

```
String x = "";
if(!response.isNull("key")) {
    x = response.getString("key");
}
```

Comment: There is no one variable in response there are more then 8 variable.

Comment: can we use replace method like response.replace(null,"");

Comment: @VikasGodiyal sorry but I don't think there's a way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether the value of the key is null or not. For example

```
if(jsonObject.get("parentId")== null){
//do something here
}
```

Or
    if JSON itself is blank

```
if(jsonObject.length() == 0)
{
//do something here
}
```

Or

```
if(jsonObject.isNull("parentId")){
    jsonObject.put("parentId", SOME_VALUE_HERE);
}
```

Comment: yes the value of key is null which is shown on app so I need to change null to blank

Comment: You can use 1st method or 3rd method that i wrote.

Comment: parent_id for which there are more then 8 variable

Comment: Yes You need to check for each of the key that you have in your JSON object. Like if(userData.getString(Config.KEY_FNAME)==null || userData.getString(Config.KEY_FNAME).equalsIgnoreCase("")){ //do something about the null values}

Comment: Ok I got it but can we use replace method like response.replace(null,"");

Comment: I don't think we can do that

Answer (score 0):

Parse the response in some model class and the in the getter functions of that model class, you could do something like

```
public Object getObject(){
return object==null:new Object:object;
}
```